# call div and put it in center of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to jump to a destination `<div>` using `href` in `html`. I am using the id of the `<div>` to call the `<div>` and successfully jump.
Here is my code.

```
   <a href='#idx'>click here</a>
            |
            |
            |
            |
<div id="idx">test scroll up</div>
```

But the position of the `<div>` is always in the top of the page if it's called.

I want the position of the `<div>` in the center of the page, when `<div>` called even click...how do I achieve that, using javascript maybe?
thanks..

Comment: what if give `margin-top` to `idx` ?

Comment: @Charlie not working,because in top there is other div..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a id="idx-link">click here</a>
```

js:

```
$('a#idx-link').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($("#idx").offset().top - 200)
    }, 800);
});
```

Change 200 appropriately based on where you want the div to be after the animation.

Answer (score 1):

For every screen height,

Check here DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/J3zyq/1/

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#gotoID').click(function() {
        var id_offset = ($(window).height() - $('#idx').height())/2;
        $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: ($("#idx").offset().top - (id_offset/1.5))
        }, 800);
    });
});
```